# How to hide rows where aggregate functions are used

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

let’s imagine here is my report:

```
select 1 from dual
union all
select 2 from dual
union all
select 3 from dual
union all
select 4 from dual
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

If e.g. i want to hide part of the report in an easy way I simply add 1 = 2 to where clause:

```
select 1 from dual
union all
select 2 from dual
union all
select 3 from dual where 1 = 2
union all
select 4 from dual
```

Output:

```
1
2
4
```

Cool! However, when select uses aggregate functions, this trick does not help. The row is generated anyway:

```
select 1 from dual
union all
select 2 from dual
union all
select max(3) from dual where 1 = 2
union all
select 4 from dual
```

Output:

```
1
2
(null)
4
```

Someone maybe know a simple, easy way to hide such rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An aggregation query with no `group by` always returns exactly one row -- even if no rows are being aggregated.

You want to filter *after* the aggregation, so use `having`:

```
select max(3) from dual having 1 = 2
```